# Display Analysis column in TFS query

Tags: tfs

I'm creating a new query for Requirement work item in TFS2015

In `Column options` for query I add two additional columns to display: `Description` and `Analysis`. Both of this fields a HTML-data type fields.

But if I run this query, then `Description` column display data normaly (with HTML tags), but `Analysis` column is totally empty.

Is it possible to somehow display `Analysis` column too in query results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Field name for Analysis tab is `Impact Assessment HTML`, not `Analysis`. So, If you want to display the content in Analysis tab, you should select **Impact Assessment HTML** column instead of **Analysis** column.